# Click Once application works when published from Visual Studio 2010 but not Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

VS2017 publish causes error on startup "cannot load file or assembly ..."  Running directly from the build works but not from the deployment in app.publish folder.  The error shows even on my development computer.  However, opening the same solution in VS2010 and publishing from there, all works as expected. I cannot find this same issue on the web.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for all things Click Once, I came across an answer for a different issue and tried it.  I upgraded the target framework to .NET Framework 4.6.1 and updated the NuGet Packages.  Afterward, I was able to publish and run the Click Once Application with no errors.